# Indication if somebody has started to write an answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, concurrency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“User X is writing an answer” - banner to appear when another user is writing too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11263/user-x-is-writing-an-answer-banner-to-appear-when-another-user-is-writing-too)

Would be nice if an author of a question can see how many people are writing their answers.

Comment: Show us in realtime what they are writing and let us edit it!

Comment: Too much Wave, John! I'm stuck with the idea that everybody can see what I'm typing in my comments while I type, which is annoying.

Comment: What psihodelia is asking is somewhat different from the other qeustion. That's about users answering at the same time, this is about being notified that someone is answering **your** question.

Comment: Dupe works the same mech. You would just have to be on the page and the only difference is a minor one, that you own the answer and to poll constantly as opposed to when you answer and then start polling.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how that could be much help. Would it have really helped you to know I was writing this answer? There are already plenty of mechanisms to allow you to see if someone has posted an answer to your question: the emails sent, the summary you get when you press the envelope, the notification bar at the top.

It's easier to do something else instead of just seeing *3 people are replying to your question*. What if they all cancel? What if it takes them a lot of time to answer? Will you just anxiously wait for them to finish? I'd rather answer some questions or simply browse around. If someone replies, I'll see it almost as soon as they've finished, which is OK for me.

Comment: If say noone is attempting to answer, then I could try to improve my original question.

Comment: It doesn't really work like that. What should you improve? You don't know what's wrong with it. Wait it out, answers aren't instantaneous.