# Let me know when someone is typing an answer or comment

Tags: feature-request, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [When answering, could we be informed that "the following people are already answering this question?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35291/when-starting-typing-an-answer-could-we-get-an-inform-that-the-following-people)

When you wait for an answer, it would be nice if a message will be popped and say: "John is typing an answer/comment" as in [Google Talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Talk).

Comment: Can you say *why* you want this? Also see [When answering, could we be informed that "the following people are already answering this question"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35291/when-starting-typing-an-answer-could-we-get-an-inform-that-the-following-people)

Comment: This should be a dupe of [Show OPs if someone is answering, live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145457/260841) instead. the current duplicate is asking for answerers to be notified; whereas this question is asking for the *OP* to be notified

Answer (score 1):

Given how often I start typing an answer, only to change my mind halfway through, I don't see how this could possibly work.

Comment: But it's optional?

Answer (score 0):

Don't bog down my connection with useless Ajax requests while I'm typing an answer, only to let the OP know I'm typing something. I'm pretty sure, statistically, the OP is not even on-line. It'd be just wasted bandwidth...

Answer (score -1):

It is not interesting. What actually matters is a real answer. Not people trying to answer.

Given that I've been often preceded by another poster who said the same thing I was writing, I guess I'm not the only one that did not submit an answer because someone was faster.

That would mean too many notifications for things that will not be concreted in an answer.