# Unethical tricks to answer questions

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I am writing this to address something I have (suspect I have) seen happening lately.

1. Note an easy question that you can solve.
2. Down vote it but don't flag it.
3. (this is a guess but rings true) Use an alt account to downvote it again if necessary.
4. Everyone skips over
5. Answer question

I have seen a number of high K users do this. Once you have moderator privileges, you can delete comments that point this out.

My question: Is there a way in the API to link users to votes to detect patterns like this?

And just curious.  Why not add a "Grab" feature that says, "Hey I got an answer, give me 5 or 10 minutes.  Penalize for failure to submit.  Honestly, just eliminating how many times people answer the same question with only one coming through would probably cut down on some of those queues.  For IT professionals, maybe answering a question while eating lunch, this is particularly frustrating.

Comment: `I have seen a number of high K users do this.` Unless you're an employee of the site, you don't actually have the ability to see who votes for what, so no, you *haven't* seen that.  You  might suspect it, but that's all.

Comment: Correct, as I indicated

Comment: You did not in fact indicate that you claim was completely false (or that you're an SE employee).

Comment: It is not true or false until it can be verified.

Comment: You don't know it was completely false.

Comment: Sure, so you claiming that it's true without having verified it means that your claim that it's true is in fact false, because you have no way of knowing that it's true.

Comment: Im asking IS IT POSSIBLE TO

Comment: No, you're stating that you have seen it.  If you were simply asking if it happens, despite not claiming to have seen it happen, that would of course be different.

Comment: Step 4 should actually say get caught by moderators and suspended, your alt accounts are all nuked. There is no step 5.

Comment: Do the mods check?

Comment: Where did you see this. Please give links. How do you know the downvotes came from the high rep users who answered? (also - only elected moderators and employees can delete comments that are not their own - so that is not factual in your question either).

Comment: "Why not add a "Grab" feature" - because then you block other people who can have legitimate answers. What if someone decides to "Grab" all questions in a tag?

Comment: And when Oded says please give links, he means in private, via a flag to mods, rather than in public here on meta.

Comment: I don't know.  I suspect.  As my edited post shows.

Comment: Either way, @Servy - what's public is public.

Comment: You need to edit the paragraph after your list too.

Comment: Please take the time to look at my answers.  Do you think I am a positive contributor to SO?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318357/moment-js-issue-adding-days-with-daylight-savings-time/21324550#21324550

Comment: What's that got to do with anything here?

Comment: @Emmentaler why would that matter to this specific question? Evidently that was a well-received answer; good job! But here you've invented a problem (it still reads *"I have seen..."* - you haven't) and come up with a repeatedly-rejected (see e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270641/add-indicator-for-the-op-to-show-that-someone-is-writing-an-answer) solution to it.

Comment: Because this matters to me.

Comment: I have invested a great deal of time in SO and I care.

Comment: Conversation being watched by other SO snobs,  helping you maintain the echo chamber. bye

Comment: I've no doubt that you have a lot of care for SO, but that's not an excuse to start slinging insults here.

Comment: Sure.  But not one person stepped to my defense even though I make a good point. I can't delete my accounts today because I got silenced by a mod so yeah, personal.

Comment: @Emmentaler ...where's the good point? You have *absolutely no evidence* that what you claim is happening actually is, your suggested fix is neither new nor particularly welcome and then you've been rude to the people who bothered to engage with it.

Comment: FRom above :My question. Is there a way in the api to link users to votes to detect patterns like this?

Comment: No, voting is anonymous.

Comment: @Emmentaler - [You can delete your account.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300185/weve-drastically-simplified-the-user-deletion-process) even if you are silenced/suspended/ect

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Exchange community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 31):

Why on earth would you do this?

To the extent that this works at all, you'd be pretty much guaranteeing that fewer people are gonna bother looking at the answer that you eventually post... So unless you're just going after the Accept bonus, or are trying to construct some weird abusive relationship with the asker themselves... This is wholly counter-productive.

But hey, let's check anyway. Looking at Ask Ubuntu over the past 90 days...

- 4989 posts got an initial downvote that wasn't retracted for at least 30 seconds
- 24 of those posts got an answer from the downvoter
- 12 of those answers weren't deleted
- 4 of those answers were posted after the downvote, 2 of which were posted after the downvote was retracted
- 1 of those answers was posted after the downvote *and* the downvote was never retracted

So... It's possible that 1 or two people do this. It's unlikely they're doing it as a trick. It's quite possible that these are [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) and the answerers are just as frustrated as everyone else.

---

Ah. You left out the "why" of all this and had me chasing shadows. That was rude.

So... You're talking about [this recent answer you posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881935/nodejs-find-object-from-array-not-contained-in-another-array/45882089#45882089), wherein you accused the other answerer of gaming the system somehow to snipe you, got all rude about it, and ended up suspended to cool down.

You should, uh, probably try to cool down.

I examined the data. Nothing even close to what you're alleging happened there. You should not accuse people of doing implausible things that you have no way to prove. You're annoyed because someone beat you to a solution; as a moderator told you already,

> Anyone can answer questions at any time. If you post a partial answer in the hope of getting the "first answer" then there's a good chance that someone else will come along an post a more complete answer before you get a chance to update yours.

Now, please walk away from the keyboard, get a nice cup of tea, and come back when you've got a cool head on your shoulders.

Comment: Mine was the first upvote

Comment: So the SO job site is worthless?   Are you saying fast rep gain isn't monetarily advantageous?

Comment: I also don't give a fig about AskUbuntu. I would love to have api access to find cheaters.  Just anonomize the data. Its not hard.  I would give it to a junior programmer.

Comment: I used AU as an example because that looked to be your top account; a co-worker just pointed out to me that most of your activity is on SO, but you're suspended there so I didn't see it. I have no idea what this has to do with jobs. The pattern on SO is a *bit* more common, but we're still talking under 1% of downvoted questions; there are more plausible explanations @Emmentaler. Anonymized data is already publicly available - how would you propose to check for this when you can't tell who a vote belongs to?

Comment: Maybe true, how bout you let the community prove it.  You are hiding behind rhetoric (and I am sure, me too) so I will state this in a new question if you agree to be civil.  And lets face it.  this is approching bullying

Comment: @Emmentaler *"this is approaching bullying"* - I agree, you're being very unpleasant. Everyone else *has* been civil.

Comment: The whole point of anonomizing data is so you can show "secret" information without revealing the the personalized portions.  Its used in healthcare, insurance, litigation, controlled studies.

Comment: Lets see what reddit says

Comment: @Emmentaler - When you post this to Reddit, do please include how [you repeatedly vandalized the post of the other person](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45882097/revisions) in an attempt to retaliate against them for having the audacity to leave a competing answer.

Comment: @Shog9: Just for clarification: are you using your ultra-powers as a Stack Exchange employee to look at vote data?  Because, otherwise, I don’t see how you (even as a ♦ moderator) could know how many answers came from a person who had downvoted the question.

Comment: I am, @Scott. I generally feel it's important to rule out claims of widespread cheating ASAP; even when the scenario is patently ridiculous, the allegation hurts everyone who is participating in good faith.

Comment: I suggest to make another query, roughly around this pattern: `SELECT Votes.UserId AS [User Link], A.OwnerUserId AS [User Link], COUNT(*) AS N FROM Posts Q, Posts A, Votes WHERE Q.Id = A.ParentId AND Votes.VoteTypeId = 3 AND Votes.PostId = Q.Id AND Votes.UserId <> A.OwnerUserId GROUP BY Votes.UserId, A.OwnerUserId ORDER BY N DESC`. Thus, you could check also for the cases, as the downvoter (to the question) and the answerer are different accounts, but somehow they seem to cooperate.

Comment: I expect that'd closely align with voters on questions that generate [reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) badges, @peterh. Which are rare precisely because so few of them are visible enough to get many votes. Which is my primary argument against this notion in the first place: if you're trying to get points for an answer, you don't bury the question!

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to add some points Shog9 hasn't covered yet.

> - Note an easy question that you can solve.
> - Down vote it but don't flag it.
> - (this is a guess but rings true) Use an alt account to downvote it again if necessary.
> - Everyone skips over
> - Answer question

Step 1: Note an easy question that you can solve... okay, that makes sense. One should only answer when he is definite that he can supply a good answer. **Step 2: Downvote it but don't flag it**... does the post need the downvote? If it doesn't, you are abusing your privilege. Downvotes are only for posts that are low-quality or off-topic per the site's respective Help Center and meta discussions. **Step 3: Use an alt account to downvote it again**.. why, oh why would you do that? That's *not* going to help at all. This step kinda reminds me of something called *using sock-puppets to apply multiple votes on the same post*. A big no-no. **Step 4: Everyone skips over**.. hehe, nice try. Usually downvoted questions do attract quite the attention. Users who are keen on moderating (using their votes and flags for example), are going to view that post and decide what to do. If it's an easy question, people <strike>might</strike> will jump on board to answer it. **Step 5: Answer question**... if your goal was to be the first answerer or something like that, why go through steps 2 and 3 when you can just... well... answer the question!

This overly complicated plan doesn't work since you have to:

- Abuse your privilege (use it incorrectly)
- Risk a ban by using a sockpuppet improperly
- You probably wasted a couple minutes voting and getting the sockpuppet to vote, not to mention the time needed to create the answer
- People are still going to see it regardless

> Honestly, just eliminating how many times people answer the same question with only one coming through would probably cut down on some of those queues.

Hey, your loss not the OP's. If you care more about *your own rep* rather than allowing the OP to get a good answer, you shouldn't be here. Period. If people are rushing in to answer your question only a few seconds later (or maybe after a minute or two), the OP has probably demonstrated the fact that little to no research has been done at all. Downvote and close and bye.

If the answers are rushed and they post first and you come out of nowhere with an exceptional answer that makes the others look like spam (hyperbole about quality here), you will be noted and upvoted and maybe the OP will accept your answer. Note, I said exceptional, not just correct. It has to be of high-quality since... well, the OP needs high-quality, correct answers.

> For IT professionals, maybe answering a question while eating lunch, this is particularly frustrating.

SE is not an arms race nor is Stack Overflow. Yes, the Fastest Gun in the West is annoying, but a better answer will shine from the rest. We all have jobs and lives, we all understand. This isn't a site where you lose rep the longer you are inactive. Just try the best you can.

---

According to Shog9, you are complaining about a user beating you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881935/nodejs-find-object-from-array-not-contained-in-another-array/45882089#45882089).

If you couldn't answer that in time, then move to the next. So what if he beat you or not. Just go ahead and answer another question. Or provide an *alternate solution* that is not a dupe of the other answer.

Comment: I don’t understand why you believe that it’s necessary to explain to the OP that the actions he describes are forbidden. He clearly knows that — his question title *includes* the word “unethical” — and the main point of the question seems to be “how can such abuse be detected/prevented?”

Comment: @Scott Mainly since Shog9 covered those points

Comment: @AnthonyPham Please explain more, how perfect is the theory of the SE, and how perfectly is it working in the practice. And, explain, that voting a question down while it doesn't deserve it, is an abuse of privilege, what is unimaginable, thus it can't ever happen.

Comment: @peterh I'm not saying anything is perfect nor will it happen. But if you really care about doing the right thing (like most high rep users), most would stray from something that is abusive

Comment: @AnthonyPham I think, there are [people](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/712093/worst-downvoters) between us, who every night wake up, give 40 downvotes on their all accounts, and then forget it next morning.

Comment: @peterh But do they downvote just to downvote? I don't think so

Answer (score -10):

As an answerer, I have the habit of voting *up* the questions I answer. It is because if they wouldn't be useful in my opinion, I wouldn't answer them.

From a rep collection perspective, I would say voting the question down, distracts the other answerers, but it also distracts the viewers. Thus, the chance that my answer will be voted up, significantly decreases.

Although the chance of - in the lack of other answers - finally my answer will be accepted, significantly increases. Particularly because it would be a "good policist, bad policist" game for the OP: he would see that his question was unfairly downvoted, but despite that, this nice guy answered it.

Beside the major ethical side of the trick, there is also a strategical problem: if my question gets accepted, it results only +15, but *I can get this +15 only once per answer*. While I can get an upvote any times. Thus, from a rep collecting perspective, I see more results in upvoting the question as voting it down.

The overwhelming majority of the reputation gained on the sites is coming from answer upvotes. It is far more as the rep gained by accepts, edits, bounties or questions. Likely all the experienced answerers know this very well. If we want to get many rep, the obvious strategy is to maximize the *answer upvotes*, every other has only secondary importance (including the possible downs).

---

However, I also think that on the SE network, many people likes to harm others on many ways, on perfectly irrational and unsaid reasons. I think, these unsaid reasons may be in many cases, that the destructive person thinks, he would gain something with the harm. Knowing their this habit, I think it is quite possible that it is more wide spread phenomenon as it would be reasonable.

---

However, I think the trick would work.

The statements of others, saying that this would attract likely a mod intervention, is not realistic in my opinion. A single, silently downvoted question, where the interaction between the downvoter and the answerer isn't trivial, probably wouldn't even attract the attention of the CMs.

And probably even the mods wouldn't see anything, because also they can't see induvidual voters. Their voting irregularity detection is tuned against the voting chains, not against such tricks.

Although it is possible to catch somebody having a habit to answer -1 voted questions.

If the answerer has 2000 rep, then he can relative silently edit the question, and revoke (or invert) his downvote on his alternate account.

Also this likely wouldn't excite the CM control, because there are no votes between different users of the same induvidual person.

Although I think, they could (and maybe they do) watch also this trick. Collecting the users with the habit of answering *and* downvoting questions, would be a singleline query with database access.

---

In my opinion, the main reason, why it is likely not a wide-spread "strategy", that the lost upvotes (by the decreased number of viewers) results more potential loss, as the increased probability of the accept.

---

In the case of the SE, I would more likely watch for an opposite pattern: the cases, as the seemingly "concurrent" answerers comment eachother's answer and then everybody silently votes everybody up.

Comment: I don't think that doing the opposite will work. I highly assume a high score question would attract viewers, not deter

Comment: @AnthonyPham I highly assume that you doesn't understand the post. This is what also I stated.

Comment: You contradict yourself with the last statement, which also encourages sockpuppeting

Comment: @AnthonyPham The last statement is about a *different* voting pattern, and it doesn't encourage anything (maybe it can be interpreted as an encouragement for the voters to not play "everybody votes everybody up" game in bikesched questions). Maybe your attitude is more antagonistic as it would be rational.