# Show if a user is currently answering your question?

Tags: feature-request

Will Stack Overflow ever implement a feature that allows users to see if someone is actively answering their question?  I feel like this feature would help make the site feel more active and give users a reason to wait for an answer longer if they see someone is in the middle of composing a long response.

Quora has this feature, and when I see someone is in the middle of answering my question I tend to stay on the site longer to wait for their response.

Comment: This is a dupe of something, I just know it.

Comment: Everything is a dupe. Everything!

Comment: Couldn't find it- send me a link and I'll delete the question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91487/can-i-see-if-someone-is-currently-answering-a-question  Wasn't tagged with feature request.  Classic.

Comment: @hub - that's because it's not requesting anything. It's a support question...

Comment: Yeah I know, I meant "classic" as in that's why I didn't find it.

Comment: I can see the next feature request coming: "a user has been answering this question for 8 hours already, surely you can tell he fell asleep!"

Comment: *[Typing an answer...]*

Comment: You can use the notification system to keep track of responses to your question. This would be more efficient then say staring at a "**[typing an answer...]**" message for 6-8 minutes.

Comment: I don't think users would stare at it.  I'm not trying to seem like a huge Quora fan/groupie but it's nice when, after you post a question, to see 2-3 "User [X] is composing an answer..."

Answer (score 4):

Things happen very quickly on Stack Overflow anyway. If your question is well-written, complete, on-topic and of interest to other programmers, expect an answer within 5 to 30 minutes after your question is posted.

You should stick around for the first 5 to 10 minutes anyway, while your question is still on the front page, to respond to requests for clarification from the community.