# indication of other people answering the question already

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When answering, could we be informed that “the following people are already answering this question”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35291/when-answering-could-we-be-informed-that-the-following-people-are-already-answ)

I was thinking - we already have dynamically added message saying "view 1 more answer to this question" and auto-loading of new comments... but what I'm missing is an option to see if somebody already started to answer this question other than me

what often happens is that I answer the question 10-20 seconds after someone else already posted their answer

if I saw that someone is already answering, I could've moved to the next  question or wait for the person to finish and see if I can give a better answer :-)

Comment: Ive seen a dupe of this--too lazy to search on the mobile site :P

Comment: @Manishearth: Just hitting close was enough, was the first suggestion. ;P

Comment: @Bobby 'Me.meta.SO.rep<3k` so I can't do that...yet :/

Comment: @Manishearth: Oh, I thought the flagging dialog would also have that functionality, my bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well actually when I write my answer on a new question I take it for granted that other people are answering it too. I write an answer because I feel I have something to say and I don't feel it's an enormous waste of time if another person write the same thing I wrote.

In short, if you have a good answer, give it and don't worry about others.

Comment: good point of view, I'll try to adapt it and possibly accept this answer then :-)

Comment: +1 - No reason in me answering too...this explains why we *don't* do this, we easily could...but intentionally don't.  There's a long-delay version when you're editing, but that's it.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, knowing that someone already started answering *could* invoke a `Oh!!-No!-somebodys-already-there- :(` feeling. So ignorance is bliss :) Start answering. And if `One new Answer pop up` appears, then check it with your answer and if yours has even 2% extra to add, go ahead!