# Feature Req: Notification when others are typing replies

Tags: feature-request, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“User X is writing an answer” - banner to appear when another user is writing too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11263/user-x-is-writing-an-answer-banner-to-appear-when-another-user-is-writing-too)

I don't like how I'll oftentimes create a carefully-crafted answer only to discover that someone else posted an answer a couple minutes before I posted mine.  I realize this would require some more server horsepower, but when I start to type an answer I'd like to see a box that tells me if other user(s) are doing the same.  I might still continue, but if it's a no-brainer, I'll let the other person take care of it and only follow up if really needed.  This would free up answerers to move on to other questions rather than playing the "race to be first" game.