# Create local temporary answer cache

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface

I've just spent 15 minutes writing a reasonably detailed answer to a question on CSS. I scroll down to click post and I get a damn access violation error that crashes the browser and kills my answer. 15 minutes absolutely wasted.

So anyway I'm thinking can we not have some opt-in javascript code that simply saves the currently worked on answer to a cookie every 30 seconds such that if the browser crashes or "whatever" we can restart the browser and retrieve the answer we've worked on?

Comment: I mean, I had references and everything!!!!! :(

Comment: /me waits for a flame war about browsers

Comment: Duplicate/related? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33455/profile-about-me-field-is-not-remembered-if-there-was-an-error-in-another-fie

Comment: @Farseeker - I specifically didn't mention it was IE for that reason. Oh wait a minute, did i just ....?

Comment: @Jon & @John - yep, looks like different ends of the same stick.

Answer (score 3):

I've learned to 'copy' a lot when making answers on these sites (and on most sites for that matter).

Comment: Yep, I "usually" do. Its like the more time you invest in an answer the more paranoid you have to become. I normally copy out to note pad but i dont see why the application cant just solve this one for us. Seems a pretty trivial problem to solve but would make the user experience that much better.

Comment: Yes, it'd be nice for an internal solution.  I actually usually just copy into the clipboard and don't bother with notepad, of course this doesn't protect me from the whole machine crashing.

Answer (score 3):

Write your answer in an external editor, and then paste when you're done.

I highly recommend using the ["It's All Text!"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4125) addon for firefox, which takes care of all the minutiae for you automatically. Just click on the little "edit" button that appears by textboxes, and your favourite editor will be invoked.

I started using this plugin after I hit <kbd>^W</kbd> too many times and lost important content (not for SO, but for work)... I am a unix user primarily, so to me <kbd>^W</kbd> means "go back a word", not "close window".

Comment: Yep. That definitely works. It'd be nice just to see it as a feature of the web application itself though. Then we wouldn't need additional programs to back us up.