# Draft questions feature request

Tags: feature-request, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting)

Sometimes it takes really long time to write a question, so "draft question" feature will be really useful.  Hypothetical: I'm creating a big question and marking it as a draft.  As soon as it is ready, I clear the "draft flag," and voila.

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting

Answer (score 1):

What I do, which I'm sure a lot of other guys/gals here do too, is to 'draft' the question offline. In Notepad or any text editor. Save it offline if need be then copy and paste as a new question when ready.

This feature request is nice at first thought, but it'll introduce a few other issues. E.g. the hassle of 'draft management', people ignoring the drafts and let the list grow. I won't be surprised if there will be some requests for 'live' questions to be set back to 'draft', etc., etc.

Comment: Give people a badge for keeping their "Draft" clean. :)
As it seems to me - question couldn't be drafted back as soon as it is published. :)

Drafted questions will be especially useful for questions starting at work time and finishing at home.

Anyway I suppose you're right.

Comment: @Kirzilla, yea I see your point on starting it off in office and finishing it at home. I'll probably draft it in my email. :)

Answer (score 0):

I select the text and ctrl-c it, then if it get's messed up I can paste it right back.