# Bug when cancelling an unsaved answer to a post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, cancel

I was answering a question on SO and received the notification that answers have been provided to the question. One of the provided answers was pretty much what I was trying to write so there was no point posting my answer (i'd rather comment on that answer etc)

So to cancel the edit, I hit refresh and received a dialog saying that if I left the page I would lose my changes and you can select an option to cancel the next page from loading in case you are accidently leaving the page...

I selected the option so that my input would be lost (As in I want to lose it) but it keeps appearing in the answer post textbox after refreshing...although each subsequent refresh doesn't warn about the input entered (which makes me wonder whether it is deliberate)...but If i'm choosing to lose my changes, I want them lost!

**Edit**
For future readers- there is a feature which is similar to this implemented as part of the system which may be confusing when reading this question/answer: [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just your browser remembering the information entered into the form and repopulating it after a refresh (this is the standard browser behaviour.) If you want to discard an answer and return to the question page I would click on the question title instead of using refresh.

The warning about navigating away from the page works by SO detecting that you have made changes. This is why you don't see the warning when you do subsequent refreshes without modifying the answer text.

Comment: makes perfect sense...sigh. too useful for there own good. thanks for the tip about clicking the question title.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, except that clicking on the question title doesn't make it go away. Shutting down the browser doesn't even make it go away.

Comment: @Graeme Perrow, I think there is now an official memory of a question and answer stored in the database in case your browser closes...if that makes sense.

Comment: @Graeme Perrow here is the link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238

Comment: @davidsleeps That explains it. Thanks