# What is the new 'Question Wizard'?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions

Today as I was posting a question on StackOverflow, and clicked on `Ask Question`, it redirected me to a 'Question Wizard'. This has never happened before. Is this new? If so, then why is it not appearing when I ask a question on Meta?

Here is the link that I was redirected to: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard

> Note: This is not a duplicate of [A Question Wizard?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55992/a-question-wizard). That is simply a feature request for the feature proposed years ago.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More details [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378057/4751173); at the moment, it's only live on Stack Overflow. If it's successful, it could be rolled out to other sites, too. You have a 50-50 chance to see it, but only when you're relatively new to the site; veteran users won't see it.

If you have any more questions about it, please check [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ask-question-wizard).

Comment: What is the SE definition of 'old' though? I am not 'new' to this site. Thank you.

Comment: See the linked post, under "What's the criteria for the test group?".

Comment: Where is that? Is there a link?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378057/4751173, penultimate paragraph.