# Implicit tagging hierarchy

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, area-51, tags, tag-hierarchy

I am aware [of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6514/tag-hierarchy-to-browse-through-tags) [similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45377/tag-hierarchy-absence-design-reasons) [requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so) but I ask this regarding SE-2.0 sites, as *the* example I will take gaming:

Both answers on the question [Should questions always be tagged with either a console/platform or with “multi-platform”?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-questions-always-be-tagged-with-either-a-console-platform-or-with-multi-p) make perfect sense to me, i.e. on the one hand this might overuse the tagging system but on the other hand it would help a lot for filtering.

Therefore I suggest a system which, in this case, would internally store the platforms to which a tag is relevant and

- if a **question is tagged** with one of these platforms, nothing special will happen and the question is to be considered platform specific (e.g. a bug which only appears on the PS3 version)
- if the **question is *not* tagged** with a platform, the *only* result will be that the tag filter mechanism works a bit different compared to what would happen if the question was (invisibly) tagged with *all* platform tags:

  - If the invisible **tagging is definite on interesting or ignore** (i.e. there is not at least one ignored and one interesting tag) the **usual mechanism** works.
  - if the **tagging is ambiguous** (i.e. contains both interesting and ignored tags), **no filtering** happens at all

The actually attributed tags must of course override this behaviour. That way questions about a game one likes but which is available for a platform one doesn't care about will still be highlighted unless specifically tagged with that platform, but no additional tags have to be used to filter a game which is only available on ignored platforms.

This can of course easily be extended to other sites, e.g. the [multithreading tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multithreading) may be interesting both general and for c++ but totally uninteresting if the question is only about a JavaScript implementation.

I am only unsure whether search should include those hidden tags, too.

Comment: This sounds like another good use of hierarchial tagging.

Comment: This would obviously also make sense for [Physics'](http://physics.stackexchange.com) subfields, see e.g. [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/318/97).

Comment: And another example: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5688/88

Comment: [Another one...](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7148/88)

Comment: This would be pretty useful for ignored/favorite tags, too. For example I'd like to see all [tag:python] questions even if it's e.g. [tag:python-3.3] and no VB.net questions, no matter which version (if there are version-specific tags for it)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Precisely my intention! And the same tag preferences btw :)

Answer (score 8):

I don't think adding this kind of complexity would make the tag system better.

Comment: not to mention the time needed to maintain such a system.

Answer (score 5):

The classification of tags in hierarchies is not necessary easy. For instance `android/facebook-android-sdk` or `facebook/facebook-android-sdk`?

Comment: I didn't claim this is always trivial, as your example shows. Actually I'd suggest that there can be more than one parent tag, so `facebook-android-sdk` could implicitly be tagged both `android` and `facebook`. (Although in this case I'd tend towards not tagging android)