# I think tags should have related tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

for example, if I set `Flash` as an interested tag, questions tagged as `Flash` will be hi-lighted, I think if someone tags a question with something clearly related like `Flex`,`Actionscipt`, etc. they may be semi-hilighted.

Just a thought.

Comment: possibly related: [implicit tagging hierarchy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58073/implicit-tagging-hierarchy).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this yourself manually.  Search for any tag you like through the [Tags page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) or by typing `[nameOftag]` into the search box.  On the right-side column, a list of related tags will show up.  You can then pick and choose the ones you want for your "Interesting Tags" list.

I'm against the automatic highlighting of related-to-interesting tags because I expect there will be too many false positives and false negatives, and because I don't want a fourth question color scheme.