# Make regex questions mention the programming language?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Could we have a feature that optionally shows more information before submitting a question, depending on what tags are used ?

The particular use case I have in mind is for the 'regex' tag on SO. Regex questions can be answered much more accurately if the poster also mentions which programming language they're using, which they don't always. Usually someone has to ask a comment to get more detail, which seems a bit of a waste of time. It'd be nice if a question tagged only with 'regex' could show a message like:

- Please specify the programming language you're using regex with.

above the 'Post Your Question' button, or even force a particular language or language-agnostic tag to be added before submitting. Maybe there are other cases where such a feature would be useful too.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57782/encouraging-users-to-specify-required-related-tags http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55943/which-tags-on-stackoverflow-do-you-think-needs-to-be-improved-and-how/55944#55944 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55992/a-question-wizard

Comment: regex questions mention the language--regex.  Does it matter, since almost all implementations are perl-compatible?

Comment: Perl is pretty much in a league of its own I think - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813775/a-successor-to-regex/4813958#4813958 - but even the others can be very different in terms of support (or lack of) for Unicode, backreferences, named capture groups, how to set things like case sensitivity and greediness, lookahead and look-behind, if and how to use a callback to do replacement etc..

Comment: Typical example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595905/regex-expression