# How to handle regex syntax highlighting

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting, code-block, regex

Many questions about regex include code blocks with language agnostic, POSIX compatible patterns, using default prettifying. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses))

[image: A freehand circle is best]

This looks kind of ugly and is confusing, since some parts are marked as literals.

How should regex code be handled?
Should syntax highlighting just be disabled for regex using *lang-none*? I think correct syntax highlighting could improve its readability, just by marking metacharacters and escaped metacharacters.

Including a language tag results in a different highlighting and seems superfluous when talking about POSIX regex—maybe even obstructive, since most people don't want to read questions about your [esoteric-language](/questions/tagged/esoteric-language). Including a language tag and using a full line of code, like `String pattern = "[a-z0-9]+";` wouldn't add any valuable information. It would only get rid of the random highlights by showing the whole pattern as literal, so no advantage over disabling highlighting completely. Of course [including a language tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86229/make-regex-questions-mention-the-programming-language) has its advantage though and a new feature should wait, IMHO, until it is clear that a question's language tag [hasn't just been forgotten](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55992/a-question-wizard).

Comment: Yeah.  Ick.  I tried several of the [language hints](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) & didn't find any that really improved matters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you'd need to submit a language filter to [highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md).

There is no `lang-regex` there yet... but there *could* be if someone contributed one!