# "Offline for maintenance" should not lose the link I tried to open

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, 500-server-error, offline

Once in a while it happens that I want to open a question from the main page and once I click it I get to [Offline for maintenance](http://sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/app_offline.htm) page. Usually that's because there's a temporary overload and the problem would not occur if I tried to open the same question for the second time. The problem is I can't conveniently ask the browser to open that question again - I'll have to go back to the main page and try to open it once again.

It sometimes happens I scroll through the main page and click "open in new tab" for questions I find interesting. If that happens during a brief outage I get to "offline for maintenance" for each and have to reopen each of them. That's a major inconvenience.

"Offline for maintenance" should provide means to easily reopen the page I originally tried to open.

Comment: Was thinking the exact same thing when SO was having some problems a couple of hours ago... I opened a few questions in a new tab and ignored that they returned the offline page. +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have added a retry link on the offline page that will help with this.  Hopefully you won't see it very often.

[image]

Comment: Great. I'll accept this once I have a chance to try the implementation out.

Comment: Just saw this after offline-time. Nice!

Comment: Geoff, will this also help with form posts, as in resubmitting all the form's data if this error comes up in response to a post?

Comment: Great. It works.

Answer (score 8):

We improved this further, now we **don't change the URL** (or redirect you at all).  With some `<iframe>` trickery to show the per-site error page (since the main error HTML is a static content-only load balancer) you can F5 to your heart's content.

<sub>Disclaimer: If you hold down F5 a temporary ban is auto-imposed by the load balancer, so don't go *completely* crazy.</sub>