# Reloading of "SO is offline" page

Tags: bug, status-completed

I'm hesitant to call this a bug and do so only because it was particularly annoying. If the powers that be want to retag as feature request, I'm fine with that.

This morning, I went to update an answer and got the "SO offline for maintenance" page. So I thought, okay, I spend too much time here anyway, I'll come back in an hour. When I came back and hit `F5` for page reload, it was still offline. Same deal two hours later.

Hmm, I thought, then I noticed the URL in the address bar was a funny one and, upon going to the "real" SO front page, it was back.

In other words, I'd just been reloading the error page. For all I know, SO had only been down for a couple of minutes.

Now that error page has a link on it to retry but it seems to me that's less intuitive than just about every other site I use where F5 will reload the page you asked for (assuming the error's been fixed), not the error page you got.

Now that I know this, I won't be using F5 again in a hurry but it may catch out others, so I'm raising an issue.

Comment: +1 - I realised this a long time ago, but never thought to mention it. It's kinda funny because there's a return URL in the address bar, which makes you think it should auto-return you on F5

Comment: +1 I did this too today for about 5 hours. I never click on links if I don't need too.

Comment: @Benny. Good, I don't feel so stupid now. Well, actually, I do but at least I'm not alone :-)

Comment: Well that makes the 2 of us :)

Comment: I swear it used to retry if you refreshed, but maybe I imagined it

Comment: For once, Michael Mrozek and I seem to be in agreement. But I suspect he was just thinking of [the retry link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66537/offline-for-maintenance-should-not-lose-the-link-i-tried-to-open/66631#66631); I know I was.

Comment: I see the question was tagged `status-completed`. What was changed in the “SO is offline” page?

Comment: @tiagoinu: see the answer below by Geoff Dalgas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added a automatic retry after 5 minutes to the offline pages which performs the following:

```
    var returnUrl = getParameterByName('return');
    $().ready(function () {
        setTimeout('autoRefresh()', 300000);
    });

    function autoRefresh() {
        document.location.href = returnUrl;
    }

    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
        var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
        var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
        var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
        if (results == null)
            return "";
        else
            return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**The offline page now works with F5**.  We now show the error page in a bit simpler fashion, with the original URL intact and a 100% height/width `<iframe>` that contains the per-site error page.

The page will still automatically retry every 5 minutes.  Also, every graduated (themed) site has an offline page that matches.

Comment: great work!

Comment: I noticed this and it is very classy.  One side effect is that the "meta is offline" page includes a link to the blog and the link loads in an `<iframe>` thus not changing the URL.  In that case `F5` refreshes the wrong page and bookmarking doesn't bookmark the blog.  Should I file a bug?

Comment: @Rick - definitely file a bug, it'll go on my todo, just comment here linking please.

Comment: Filed here: [Offline page contains links that are trapped in an IFRAME](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97696/offline-page-contains-links-that-are-trapped-in-an-iframe).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be accomplished by having the static offline page attempting an Ajax request to determine if SO is back up, and re-directing if so.