# Is Stack Overflow offline?

Tags: discussion, support, offline

Has anyone else seen this today morning? Does it happen generally or is there some problem at my side?

[image]

Also after SO is up I was still not able to get it worked by refreshing. I have to open new window for SO to work. Also copy paste of URL didn't work. I have to manually enter the URL.

Has any one else faced same before?

**Edit**

Why SO is going offline again and again today??? I faced it 3 times from morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens when they push a new build, and refreshing doesn't help. The text on the page describes it pretty well:

> Routine maintenance usually takes less than an hour. **You may retry your request** or if this turns into an extended outage, we will **post details on the blog**

You have to click the "retry your request" link to retry; refreshing just refreshes the error page. There's a [bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76634/reloading-of-so-is-offline-page) trying to get it changed so retrying will actually retry the request

---

**Edit**: I don't know if this is the only reason SO has been down recently, but one of the devs [tweeted this](http://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/33000674866237440) earlier:

> Heads up #stackoverflow users, we'll be offline for a bit tonight around 11PM EST for some back-end work, planned outage for a few items

Comment: see the edit.