# Offline page contains links that are trapped in an IFRAME

Tags: bug, status-completed, offline

A [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76634/reloading-of-so-is-offline-page/96957#96957) to the way that sites display their offline page preserves the URL that the user requested in the title bar of the browser instead of redirecting to an error page.  This is a great feature because you can simply use refresh or `F5` to reload the page.

The way it works is to embed the site-specific offline page in an `<iframe>` that takes up the whole page.  The only problem with this is that the site-specific offline page contains a link to the blog:

[image]

as a simple link:

```
<a href="http://blog.serverfault.com/">blog</a>
```

and this link is trapped in the `<iframe>`.  If you follow the link and press `F5`, it will not refresh the blog, and if you bookmark the blog, it won't bookmark the right link.

Comment: IIRC, the fix is `<a href="http://blog.serverfault.com/" target="_parent">blog</a>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for filing this, it will be fixed in the next build with a parent `target` added to each link (since we *know* it's one level deep).