# Could the error page have a retry button?

Tags: feature-request, 500-server-error

For some errors it will not make sense, but for some errors (e.g. 500 status codes) it might make sense to have try again button on this page:

[image: cat haz to retrie]

Because url gets redirected to `/error?....` refreshing the page does not work.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but similar in spirit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66537/offline-for-maintenance-should-not-lose-the-link-i-tried-to-open

Comment: What about an automatic retry with JavaScript WebSockets (push, no polling)?