# Error message saying that a moderator tag must be present when asking a question

Tags: bug, asking-questions, error-message, draft, moderator-tags

When asking a question on Meta, I've encountered a bug which consists in an error message saying that a moderator tag must be present. Here is an example:

[image]

Steps to reproduce this bug:

1. Ask a question and tag it with a moderator tag without posting it.
2. Let your draft be saved ([it's saved automatically every 45 seconds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65360/349538)) and then close the tab.
3. Click the Ask Question button on the same site again after closing the tab (use the site's Ask Question button, using the browser's Reopen Closed Tab won't always work).
4. Remove the moderator tag and the error message should show up.

This isn't a big deal since it still allows posting the question without the moderator tag and doesn't allow posting it with the moderator tag, but I still think that this bug should be fixed.

<sub>PS: In case you're curious about how I noticed this bug, I usually put moderator tags (or [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) on non-meta sites) on my questions while I'm writing them so that I don't submit by mistake and then remove them when I'm ready to post.</sub>