# How do I delete the draft posting?

Tags: support, draft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a clear button when a saved draft is loaded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68140/add-a-clear-button-when-a-saved-draft-is-loaded)

How do I delete these draft things? I wrote an answer to a question then decided not to post but the draft answer won't go away. I've tried closing the browser and starting it again, and also tried blanking out the box, but neither of these ideas worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238):

> You only get one draft (if you start
>   answering a new question, old draft is
>   blown a way).

Clear the box, type something and wait for the draft to be saved (there will be a message below the textbox).

Comment: That saves another draft, it doesn't delete it.

Comment: @Kinopiko, did you try it? It works for me.

Comment: @Popular Demand: Yes I did try it. I cannot get rid of the text. I want to remove the draft completely. With the above method, if I delete all the text, it will not save it, and when I reload the page, the old text is still there, seemingly perpetually. The only thing this answer lets me do is change the text, not delete it.

Comment: As I said, if you save a draft for a question you don't care about, your other draft will go away.

Comment: OK Simon, I give up.

Comment: @Kinopiko, if you're willing to keep trying, I'm willing to as well. You said "when I reload the page" in your last comment. That makes it sound like you did not go to an entirely different question before saving the "throwaway" draft. Could you provide details about the _exact_ steps you used in your attempt to repro?

Comment: Ctrl-S doesn't work in Chrome; I get the save dialog to save the page.

Comment: Ctrl-S doesn't work in Firefox either.  Same behavior.

Comment: Finally, Ctrl-S in Internet Explorer just makes my computer go "ding" and does nothing.  Does this even work on other Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: @Chris FYI: the Ctrl+S functionality was removed [in November](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69831/is-the-save-draft-keyboard-binding-broken).

Comment: I'd personally just like to know why the solution is to "wait" [for your browser, your system, or the server] to do something. I too am having this problem. Waiting 30 seconds for the draft to be saved is not ideal.

Comment: @Brian: According to Mr. Atwood in the [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69831/is-the-save-draft-keyboard-binding-broken) DMA posted, it was to effectively lighten the load on the server.  I'm not [convinced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69962/add-an-option-to-save-draft-and-or-reset-draft-manually) however.

Answer (score 10):

[Since March 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68957/manually-clear-saved-question-drafts/126299#126299), there is a "discard" just at the side of the posting button, if a draft has been saved. Clicking it will erase the draft:

[image]

Comment: I saw you wondered about the community wiki thing. That's just because the (old) question was made community wiki [by its author](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/67163/revisions). Then all new answers are CW too. Now, as the author is no longer a member here and cannot move the "Accepted" answer to this one: why not remove your above answer? You're not getting any rep from it anyhow. Then I will edit this answer into the existing answer.

Comment: @Arjan I got the necromancer badge :D

Comment: Are you saying you want to keep this mess alive for a badge...?

Comment: @Arjan but his post is not CW

Comment: We can still edit it into that... :-)