# Add a clear button when a saved draft is loaded

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, draft

I can't believe this has not been asked, but I can't find it, so here it goes.

The save draft feature is cool, but I had a question that I figured out half way through.  It would be nice to have a clear button to clear out all the input.

It is not that it is very hard to go and manually clear out the title, question and tags, but the feature of the drafts seems incomplete without it.

If there is a clear button that I could not see please point it out to me.

Comment: It's never been asked as a clear-cut feature-request, but [there was one question asking if it was possible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67163/how-do-i-delete-the-draft-posting). Thus to answer your final sentence, no there is no existing method to clear everything.

Comment: Have to favorite this so I can [feature-request] restoring the fields after I accidentally hit the clear button.

Comment: Arrrg, they've removed the option to manually save now.  I've put in a [request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69962/add-an-option-to-save-draft-and-or-reset-draft-manually) to effectively add a save button now, clearing is included too.  :)

Comment: Watch out. [My question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68957/137977) about the same (or very very similar) issue has been **declined**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per [Manually clear saved question drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68957/manually-clear-saved-question-drafts/126299#126299) .

For those fastidious about clearing drafts (for whatever reason) this will be available in the next build.

[image]
<sub>Also available on answer drafts</sub>

Answer (score 5):

There is no clear button.

**BUT** I have written a UserScript that adds one:

[Manual Draft Save - Save a draft on demand](https://stackapps.com/questions/2086/manual-draft-save-save-a-draft-on-demand)

Answer (score 2):

Your answer (question) draft will be cleared anyway as you start writing a new answer (question). There's only one answer (question) draft per user per site at any one time.

Comment: To be [very precise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238): one draft for questions, and another for answers, and I think this is per site (not shared among sites for a single user). And I guess the draft will only be cleared when the new one is saved after 45 seconds?

Comment: @Arjan Thanks, fixxord.

Answer (score -2):

________NO________!!!!!

**wrong, bad, wrong, bad**.

**Why** would you need this?  In 1996 they used to have a [Reset Form](http://www.antharia.com/blog/index.php?id=248) button on every web form.  People stopped doing that around 2000 or so.  Why are you trying to turn stackoverflow into a time machine?

[image: reset form]

[Jakob Nielson](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20000416.html) wrote about this too.  This has no use and if you accidentally click it you will lose your work.  **Don't add this**.

I really see this "feature" anyway as an excuse not to build out the [drafts feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73148/list-all-my-drafts). The button doesn't even match - it's hacky and I don't like it.

Comment: On Stack Exchange, there's a nice confirmation when clicking "discard": *Are you sure you want to discard your draft?*

Comment: __No__!  It's wrong!  The button shouldn't even be there!

Comment: Big difference between a "reset form" button on a singe entry form and a clear button for something that persists over time.

Comment: Oh, oh, a downvote?? Oh that doesn't mean I'm wrong.

Comment: True, a downvote doesn't mean you're wrong, but having to use that much bold is not making your case very strong. ;-)

Comment: @Arjan ______NO_______