# Is the save draft keyboard binding broken?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, draft

Ctrl+S doesn't work for me on any of the sites.

When my cursor is focused in the textarea and I hit Ctrl+S I get the browser default of saving the entire webpage rather than saving my draft.

I'm using Firefox 3.6.12. Is anyone else having this problem?

Comment: Repro on IE8, XP. Ctrl+S ain't doing anything here.

Comment: Ditto for me in Chrome (dev), but the periodic saving is working.

Comment: Confirmed ... somebody made this go away ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was removed, it was 50+ lines of javascript, served literally millions of times a day, for what is effectively an easter egg.

Posts are auto-saved as drafts every 45 seconds; nothing else needs to be done.

update: If you would like to have a "save right now button" George Edison graciously submitted a user script to do this at [Manual Draft Save - Save a draft on demand](https://stackapps.com/questions/2086/manual-draft-save-save-a-draft-on-demand)

Comment: There really should be a button or some option to force the save then.  I really don't want to have to wait until it autosaves if I _must_ close the browser or otherwise navigate away from the page.

Comment: @JeffM: ...and **done!** http://stackapps.com/questions/2086/manual-draft-save-save-a-draft-on-demand