# Ability to save partial answer as a draft

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting)

Some answers take a while to complete, and sometimes they require more than one seating for completion. It would be nice to be able to save answers as "drafts".

For example, say I have been typing an answer for the past 15 minutes, but I need to leave my computer for a while or switch to another computer. It would be nice to be able to save my answer so that I can edit it and finalize it at a later time.

I realize that I could just copy the text into a text editor and email it to myself or save it to my desktop, but I think it would be nicer to have the functionality built into the site. There have been times where I have been halfway through answering a question when I have to leave and I end up closing the window and not answering the question.

**Update**
@Tim Stone pointed out that the system will automatically save a draft for you on a set interval. I was unaware of this feature -- somehow I never noticed it. Some other people have reported that the feature is somewhat inconsistent and/or unreliable.

I would tend to agree with @nhahtdh that since the functionality to save an answer as a draft already exists, there should be a way for the user to call the "Save" function themselves.

Comment: The system will [automatically save a draft for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238) already, on a set interval.

Comment: I am totally weirded out by this feature as implemented. Last night, I was in the middle of writing an answer. Then I switched to a different computer - _half_ the answer was saved, but not the previous 15 minutes of work. I also remember once seeing a "draft saved" notice beneath the textbox, and I went, "cool, [just what I wanted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135775/164985)" but most of the time I don't see one, and I have no idea whether I can rely on my draft being saved.

Comment: Wow, I never even noticed that feature

Comment: @Ziv: That's my experience with the feature as well. It's very inconsistent and unreliable. I still find myself using the clipboard or a text editor.

Comment: If they automatically save a draft already, why not provide a button to manually save the draft?

Comment: @Bolt maybe it's worth looking into then - we have the tools after all and we have devs here willing to fix bugs with joy. :) First thing I'd check is maybe the live refresh it messing with the draft saving..

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69831/is-the-save-draft-keyboard-binding-broken?rq=1 . There used to be a key binding; it was removed; there's a [user script you can install](http://stackapps.com/questions/2086/manual-draft-save-save-a-draft-on-demand). That being said, I support this question, since IMHO present implementation is spotty to the point of unreliability.