# List of my open draft-answer edits

Tags: feature-request, support, questions, draft

Sometimes, I do take time to answer a question. And it so happens, that I switch off my computer (more or less voluntarily) in the meantime. Still I can get back to my edits when I remember the precise question. But what can I do, if I don't remember it?

That is: Is there a way to get the list of my draft-answers? Or: a link to the currently pending draft-answer.

Also related: Is there a way to explicitly save such a not yet posted question? It seems this is done automatically, but sometimes the last edits are gone.

Comment: FYI, it only saves one draft answer per site. So there wouldn't be a 'list', but it would be nice to have a link to that draft in say the 'answers' tab of the profile page.

Comment: @toxalot: Thank you - maybe this is the reason why I believe that some of my draft-answers are lost?

Comment: Regarding your last __edits__ to drafts sometimes being gone: drafts are only saved [every 45 seconds](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/131713), not in real time or on change. I believe this is for network/performance reasons. However, if you're feeling adventurous, there is [a userscript for saving drafts on demand](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69885/131713).

Comment: The worst part about this situation (which I am currently in) is that you can no longer answer anything for fear of wiping out the draft! I wonder if it could be accomplished with the Data Explorer.