# Old question keeps reappearing in the form for asking a new question

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, draft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting)

I'd like to ask a new question on SO, but when I click the "Ask Question" button, the form is pre-filled with all my text from the previous question, which I asked a few days ago. I tried this in another brand browser (Internet Explorer and Google Chrome) and the same text showed up.

I saw some mention on this site that this is a new "draft" feature? But I've already published the last question, so I don't see why it should be showing as a draft now. Also, how do I remove this so I can write my new one?

Comment: This happened to me as well once. I guess it's the draft mode. Just replace the title and text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete the draft posting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67163/how-do-i-delete-the-draft-posting), [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting)

Comment: and to the friendly patrons who voted me down - this is an actual bug, after I cleared and posted a new question, it didn't reappear. So something was wrong. Thanks for your support.

Comment: sounds like draft mode to me, not a bug.

Comment: Notice I had already posted the question that was re-appearing. Thus it sound(ed?) like a bug in the draft mode feature. 

Btw why is this downvoted? Reporting a valid bug gets a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

This happend to me many times. It is not fatal bug, though.

You can clear/save your draft fast, by using [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/2086/manual-draft-save-save-a-draft-on-demand) Chrome/FF extension.

PS: Internet Explorer is not a valid browser ;)