# Don't warn about leaving the page if the text in question has a draft saved

Tags: feature-request, answers, draft

Now that there's [a draft feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting), it seems unnecessarily annoying to warn about leaving the page for answers that have been saved as drafts, when they can be trivially recovered.

While drafts are only retained for a short period of time, if the answer matters, the answerer will probably have second thoughts soon after navigating away from the question.

Comment: Is it just me or is this [status-completed]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the drafts are especially useful for something like a BSOD or a power failure where I'm actually in the middle of writing an answer when it disappears.  But if I've gotten distracted, if I'm on another tab and accidentally (or intentionally) hit the browser's close button without thinking about it, I may not even remember 5 minutes from now *which* post I was writing an answer to.  I may not even remember *that* I was writing an answer!  This is especially true at work when I'm writing in little spurts at a time and have to shift my attention constantly.

I think the warning should stay.  The two features are complementary.  The warning is a reminder that I never finished answering the question; then, I can actually close it anyway, secure in the knowledge that I'll (probably) be able to get it back later.

Answer (score 5):

I thought about posting a question like this earlier, but [drafts only autosave every 45 seconds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238). I can type a *lot* of words in 45 seconds, and I wouldn't want to lose them by accidentally leaving the page.

Of course, this comes down to "what would bother you more, losing 45 seconds worth of typing or having to see the 'leaving on purpose?' popup more often," which is purely a matter of personal preference.

Comment: entire civilizations have been destroyed for less.

Comment: @Jeff link or it didn't happen

Comment: if I understand @Jeff correctly, he's saying that entire civilizations have been destroyed over reasons more trivial than losing what text can be typed in 45 seconds. So the feature of warning you that you might lose your text is necessary, as it might very well prevent the collapse of modern civilization.