# "Ask a Question" question box has previously asked question

Tags: support, asking-questions, draft

I asked a question yesterday and today I have another, but when I click on the "Ask Question" button the text box where you type the contents of the question is filled in with the previous question. I tried navigating to other pages and then back to the question page and nothing. I restarted my browser and it's still there. Is this a bug or is it my browser? I'm using a portable version of Firefox 3.6.9. I don't have any add-ons that "auto-fill" or anything like that.

I suppose this isn't a big deal or anything, but my first thought was that this could be confusing to some people. Like if they delete it and type a new question it's actually editing their previous post or something.

Edit: This is happening on SO, not here on Meta. Here it seems to be fine. Also I haven't had this issue with any of the exchange sites either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug, it is a feature!  Seriously though, there is now a saved draft feature.

The draft will be saved every 45 seconds if I remember correctly. waffles gives more details about the feature here: [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238)

Comment: Ah, ok that's pretty cool. I wonder if it should be a bit more obvious though? Maybe it's just me though.

Comment: This just happened to me. When the form displayed my previous question, I clicked "discard" and that removed the draft. Now I can ask a new question.

Comment: That cannot be a feature. If I already post the question, the draft should be eliminated.