# Ask question bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, asking-questions, draft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Ask a Question” question box has previously asked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68068/ask-a-question-question-box-has-previously-asked-question)

I meet a little strange event today: while I'm editing a question, suddenly I remember that I have another question to ask. So I open the second tab to create the second question. But its content is the same as the first question that I'm editing! I guess this is a feature that only let a member ask a question at a time, so I finish the first question, then push "Ask question" again.

But even after that, the question box appears still filled by the first question content! Am I only permitted to ask 1 question at a time? And the tag field has some strange things in it, as shown below.

I have the feelings that I should wait a little before asking the second question. But after half hour waiting, it's the same whenever I push the "Ask question" button.

[image: Bug Ask Question]

Comment: The first part of your question refers to the draft feature.is the tag bug reproducible? I got that once, but a reload made it go away

Comment: @abel: I have encountered it 2 times, and now I can't re-produce it,too

Comment: I got that once more. I think it's due to incompletely loaded javascript. A reload makes it go away.

Comment: @abel: if it's like you said, maybe better if they use something like document.ready()

Answer (score 4):

> ut even after that, the question box appears still filled by the first question content! Am I only permitted to ask 1 question at a time?

That's not a bug, that's a [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238)

> - We save drafts automatically for all new answers and new questions once every 45 seconds
> - You only get one draft for an answer and one for a question. (If you start a new post, old draft is blown away.)

---

> And the tag field has some strange things in it, as shown below.

Seems like the hint-text for tags was not cleared

Comment: @Sathya: I think it's better if the website know that my question has been published, and not display it again. When it appears the first time, I think I have accidently click some kind of "edit" my question. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Sathya: how about the tag cloud in the image.. sorry for being to perfect, but it looks not very nice.

Comment: @Hoang edited, I cannot reproduce the tag cloud issue here - try refreshing the page ?

Comment: @Sathya: May you try following my procedure described in the question? I don't know what happens, but now everytime I click: "Ask Question", the tag cloud appears like the picture above. May the draft saved before I added the tag?

Comment: @HoàngLong I tried to reproduce the bug using the steps you outlined, but I cannot seem to do so.

Comment: @Sathya: The bug for me is still here, but I need to post question to reproduce it. Where should I post a fake question to make it appear again?

Comment: @HoàngLong try posting in meta itself, w/ a disclaimer not to close it because you're trying to repro a bug

Comment: @Sathya: I have encountered the bug another time in stackoverflow, when I lost internet connectivity while posting an answer. But now I just seems can't re-produce the bug. Maybe it has something to do with the timing, or someone has already fixed it