# Why does SO take me to already asked question when I click Ask Question?

Tags: support, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Ask a Question” question box has previously asked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68068/ask-a-question-question-box-has-previously-asked-question)

Today, I am getting weird behavior in SO, when I click Ask Question, it takes me to an editable version of the last question I asked and allows me to ask it again, already all typed up.

It occurs on a second computer too, to the same question.

How do I get out of this weird state?

Comment: No repo for me, although I haven't asked a question in a while

Comment: It's a saved draft of your question. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I edited the pre-filled in question to blank it all out and posted.  My new question posted fine and the old one remained. Now when I Ask again, it does not happen anymore.

The bizarre state has now gone away.