# When I ask a question, the form is populated with the last question I asked

Tags: support, questions, draft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Ask a Question” question box has previously asked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68068/ask-a-question-question-box-has-previously-asked-question)

[how to pass strings to functions not by ref (Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951989/how-to-pass-strings-to-functions-not-by-ref-ruby)

I asked this one several hours ago.  Since then I have closed the browser, re-opened it, and now when I try to ask a new question, the form gets populated with the old question's text.  Why is this happening?

Comment: Sounds wrong.  It ought to preserve what you type only as long as you didn't actually post the question (or answer).  A feature that dates back a while when users were complaining about losing their carefully typed text after their browser burbs.

Comment: This must be 'by design', the same happens when I move between my laptop and desktop.

Answer (score 5):

This is a "feature" of the SO system. So for instance, if you lose your browser, you don't lose your data. Alternately, if you accidentally navigate away, most of the work (since the last save) is still there. It "expires" after a while, or if you answer a question then it goes away.

If you want to force it away, go answer another question ;)

**edit** whoops, he said "question" ...

Now that Jeff undeleted my answer, I'll point out that I read this as answer at first, but apparently it works for Q's too. Just thought I would mention that.

Comment: this is also true for question asking.. we save 1 answer and 1 q

Comment: Oh, thanks Jeff. I didn't know that about the Q

Comment: As you can see from my question, I already posted that question, shouldn't it disappear now? (You can alos see how long has passed since, right?)

Comment: @ItayMoav you should _not_ still have it on the same computer that you posted from, so long as you didn't have two tabs open to the question when you asked it (allowing the "post and clear" operation to get overwritten by the "window has a textbox with text in it that has not been posted" action)

Comment: Personally I would call this a fluke and go on. If it repeats let us know for sure and poste haste ;)

Comment: @JeffAtwood: just experienced the same problem; clicked on other Qs but whenever going to "Ask", it's there. So I've to manually clear the fields?

Comment: Have you "asked" a new question since then? Yes, you would need to clear the fields manually.

Comment: This just happened to me. When the form displayed my previous question, I clicked "discard" and that removed the draft. Now I can ask a new question. read more: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126299/182792