# "Ask Question" button is diverting me to an editable version of the last question I've asked?

Tags: bug, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When I ask a question, the form is populated with the last question I asked.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90738/when-i-ask-a-question-the-form-is-populated-with-the-last-question-i-asked)

When I press the "Ask Question" button I am being diverted to an editable version of the last question that I asked. Why is this?

I am using Firefox 5 on Windows XP SP3.

EDIT - the question was successfully submitted and has answers next to it

Comment: What's with the 'kin downvotes?!

Comment: Ya, not sure how people can _disagree_ with this here. A down-vote is not a solution, even if this isn't a bug. looking for an explanation can hardly be deemed too much to ask.

Comment: Downvoting is not a problem. Downvoting *without* commenting should be a capital offence.

Comment: not saying I'm downvoting you for that comment, but I'm not saying *I'm not,* either.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you actually posted that previous question?

A draft of the question is saved but it should be cleared when you actually submit the post.

Given that you did post it, did you start an edit and the abandon it?

Comment: Yes, it's on the site and has multiple answers from yesterday. The only thing I've changed recently is moving to FF5 today