# Ask a question shows my previous question

Tags: feature-request, bug, draft

I just joined android.stackexchange.com and made my first [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/190167/how-can-i-buy-a-micro-usb-cable-for-my-phone?noredirect=1) Friday. And today I tried to create a new one and got in edit mode of my previous one.

This question has some answers already, and it looks like it is related to the Save Draft feature.

["Ask a Question" question box has previously asked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68068/ask-a-question-question-box-has-previously-asked-question)

Also there are some feature requests to add a Manual Save option:

[Add an option to save drafts manually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69962/add-an-option-to-save-drafts-manually)

I think the Save Draft is great because it can save you if your browser crashes or the electricity fails, which does happen in the third world country I live in.

**But my issue is if I've already posted my question, why isn't the draft eliminated?**

It is very confusing, and took me several tries to understand what was happening and some searches to learn what should I do next to post my new question.

At the minimum I suggest adding a message telling user a draft has been recovered like MS Word does when opening after a crash.

Also it is very weird that this happened to me just now after so many years on SO. I only have 160 questions. But because this is the first time it happened to me, I think maybe it is a issue with this particular site.

Comment: Before anyone votes to close this as a duplicate, things have changed since 2010, when [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68071/323179) was posted. According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/323179), it should only keep the draft when you "do not successfully submit" the post.

Comment: You posted / created the post on the full website, right? Not in the Android or iOS app? And you're asking the new question form the website, right?

Comment: @rene Correct to both statement. Im on PC. google chrome.

Comment: @DonalDuck, I just check your profile for the query to see image links. But is giving me time out.