# Does SO, et. al. now remember partially entered answers between page loads?

Tags: support, answers

I wasn't sure if this was a new feature I was seeing or a quirk in my browser/session.  I was answering a question on SO and decided not to finish it (I realized I didn't know as much about the subject as I thought my answer out).  To clear the answer I reloaded the page... but my answer was still there.  I was curious, so I deleted the text, re-loaded the page, and it was still there! I even went so far as to close the tab (in Chrome, so the process exited), and then load it in a new tab, and the answer was still there!

At the time I thought it was a new feature - some sort of utilization of HTML5 localStorage to save someones answer in case of a browser crash or somesuch (and given how lengthy some answers can be, this seemed useful).

However, out of curiosity I just tried to duplicate this behavior again today (saw this behavior a day or two back), but was unable to do so.  Wasn't sure if I wasn't triggering the conditions correctly, or if what I was seeing the other day was just erroneous.

Comment: Yes, it does! This was a new feature introduced on [October 24th, 2010](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238). You can find various data on it in the [draft tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/draft).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. As you compose your post, it is automatically saved as a draft, allowing you to come back to it later.

[Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting)