# Does Stack Overflow have a draft saving feature?

Tags: support, draft

Every time I type a question in Stack Overflow , I occasionally see a "Draft Saved" string under the question area. Does this mean that Stack Overflow has a draft saving feature? If so, how is it used?

Comment: +1 I find a lot about this feature on meta, except for a decent faq item... you might turn this post into a faq-proposed question, and make the title more "compliant" (i.e. how does the draft saving feature work?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

It has been in place for a while. See here: [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238)