# Save incomplete questions

Tags: support, editor, draft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting)

Just wondering are there any plans to enable saving of incomplete questions, allowing you to finish them off and submit later? (Unless it already exists and I don't know about it?)

Answer (score 2):

Your last post is always saved once every 45 seconds. Visiting the URL of the last post will result in the question/answer section pre-populated with the draft.

Note: Only the **last incomplete** post is saved as draft.