# Oops something bad happened? When will this happen?

Tags: discussion, support

I was answering a question, and suddenly I got the following error twice in a row.

Why is this error occuring? Can I do anything to avoid it?

[image: something bad happened]

Comment: So, where's the additional information? Which question were you trying to post an answer to? Which answer did you try to post?

Comment: Nothing you can do to avoid it, but keep in mind that answers are saved as draft (per question) so all your data is safe, even if you close the page and come back later. :)

Comment: You found the bonus kitten!

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - Where is the draft saved though? Is it saved to SO servers, or just to local-storage in the browser?

Comment: @cdeszaq according to the comments made on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/152859) it's "server side" which most likely means Stack Overflow servers, not local storage. (So if you browse from different machine, you'll still have it)

Comment: @cdeszaq OK found the full details [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111050/what-are-the-details-implementation-of-the-draft-feature) - in short, it's stored in redis.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually related to your [other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120253/are-your-browser-cookies-enabled-for-this-domain). What's happening is a security violation. Something must be seriously broken with your browser or with a proxy you're behind. Looking at the logs, it seems it's deciding at random whether it should send your user cookie or not.

Comment: You mean that such error can happen if registered user start answering a question and when he submit the reply his authentication is "gone" for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Some internal error must have occurred. Possibly a deployment just a you were posting yoru answer (as @Sha Dow Wiz Ard suggests in his comment).

On a vary high transactional site like StackOverflow this will happen on occasion - there is nothing you personally can do about it.

Comment: Indeed - new builds are also deployed occasionally, check the revision number in the bottom right of every page (e.g. now it's `rev 2012.1.25.665`) most likely they deployed new revision so it caused slight down time.

Answer (score 0):

The exact reason this might occur is knowledge that only Stack Exchange employees will have (and maybe a few other privileged people) - but, no, as per the message on the page, this is an error on their side and nothing you can do about it.

Someone might thank you for bringing this to attention if they're unaware of it being a persistent, recurring issue, but I'm sure SE will know of it and either A) fix whatever caused/is causing it, or B) leave it, as it occurred under exceptional circumstances at a specific time which is out of their hands.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error when I lost the session Connection from `StackOverFlow` site and refresh the my page. This happened because my internet connection was changed from one gateway to another gateway. It doesn't happen normally with regular StackOverFlow site page, but yes, it always happens in Chat Room's Access Page.