# Drafts for edits get lost on leaving the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, android-app

When editing in the Stack Exchange Android app and navigating away to get some reference URLs the text is gone when I go back into the app.

Seems like the edit isn't kept in memory. Can you please save them in memory? (drafts)

Comment: Not a bug, drafts are saved only when posting new question. You can change this post to feature request asking to apply drafts to edits as well. There is [existing request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130071/152859) for edit drafts but it's for the desktop site version.

Comment: Changed to feature request, thanks.

Comment: Yes, please! I lost on a non-trivial edit I was trying to make when I went back to the browser to copy the URL to paste into my answer. I know it is preferable make one large edit rather than a series of trivial edits (hello community wiki!), but if one does not have a desktop handy, I would see no alternative to having to post multiple small edits to add a citation.

Comment: I'm retagging this; this is a bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think you were interpreting this as being about closing the edit to browse around within the app, then returning to the edit within the app. This bug is really about _leaving the app_ to check on some other application, then returning to the app - the edit gets reset, and it really shouldn't be, any more than alt+tabbing away from a browser window should reset an edit to its original state.

Comment: @doppelgreener right, if that is the case I agree it is a bug. Cheers! (Also removed the draft tag as it is not relevant)

Comment: Related (not dupe, is newer): [Screen sleep loses edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261499/screen-sleep-loses-edits)

Answer (score 8):

I've just experienced this in Android App v1.0.50 on a HTC One running Android 4.4.3.

Here's how to reproduce it:

1. Begin editing an answer. Make some changes.
2. Hit Home, or switch to another app using your app switcher. You might do this to visit your browser to check something you're going to mention in your edit.
3. Switch back to the Stack Exchange app. Look at the answer you were editing. Your edit is now gone, and you're staring at the original version of the answer.

This is kind of like if my edit of this answer would be reset and forgotten if I alt+tabbed during editing to another window.

If you were making a non-trivial edit, you might feel pretty annoyed by this point. Luckily for me I was just changing a couple of words in an answer when I noticed this, and I switched to my browser to check one of the words.

Note that this *does not happen* when editing questions. Editing a question preserves the edit properly.

Comment: This also happens in iOS app, when leaving while editing, the app gets back to Feeds when you return and the edit is lost.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ouch, at least in the Android app it stays on the edit page for that answer.

Comment: I repro'd this earlier today, I think I know what's causing it. Except a fix soon!

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi any update, 10 weeks later?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi just in case you missed my ping... (and yes, [it's still happening](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259950/all-edits-lost-after-android-stackexchange-app-is-paused-and-resumed?lq=1))

Comment: @Kasra confirmed today on Moto X, Android 4.4.4

Comment: @Kasra so I take it this bug can't be fixed?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi See also: [Screen sleep loses edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261499/screen-sleep-loses-edits)

Comment: This... really shouldn't be happening anymore. It was fixed at some point but I might've broken it again, I'm trying to do repros and check on it right now.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Thanks for the reply, we'd appreciate the checks!

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for the long delay on this, I thought I had fixed it already but it turned that I only fixed a red herring. It's fixed as of version 1.0.71 coming out later today or tomorrow.

Keep in mind, this is only fixing the loss of modifications to an answer when momentarily leaving the app, if you close the app from the app switcher or run out of memory while using other applications, it's still possible to lose your edit. This is because we don't do the full drafting logic we have for questions/answers when you're editing. That should also be implemented, but it's only loosely related to this much more important bug.

Comment: Working now for me with 1.0.71.  Thank you!

Comment: +1, thanks! I haven't updated my version of the app yet, so I can't say if it works...but [this fellow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261929/266359) claims to have v 1.0.71 and still experiencing this bug.

Comment: @Shokhet the situation I described is different. I never go out the app, just navigate from draft to the question and back