# Screen sleep loses edits

Tags: bug, android-app

If you edit a post using the Android app and the screen turns off to save battery, upon resume the post is still there for editing, however all edits are lost. This doesn't seem to happen every time though, which is the strange thing.

This is on version 1.0.68 on Lollipop.

Comment: Long time bug, dev couldn't really fix it. (well, some bugs are harder to fix than others, not much we can do)