# Answer draft is blank everytime go for edit it

Tags: bug, android-app, draft

**Specifications**

App version 1.0.71

Android 4.1.2

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Go to a question and click *Add answer*
2. Write whatever you want in the answer body
3. Go back to the question with back arrow of the StackExchange app
4. Now you will see the *Edit draft answer* bottom, click it

Again in the write answer page, the content is blank, the text you wrote was ereased. There is nothing to edit, really an annoying bug for android app jeje

**Note**
I never go out the app, just navigate from draft to the question and back

**Note2** this works fine in the previous app version that I was using, sorry I don't know the number but I installed more than 2 month ago.

**Update with version snapshot**
[image: version 1.0.71 on android 4.1.2]

**Edit Jan 2016:**
This wasn't a duplicate question and it is not answered in the [suggested post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219840/drafts-for-edits-get-lost-on-leaving-the-android-app/261516#261516), please read [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219840/drafts-for-edits-get-lost-on-leaving-the-android-app/261516#comment854168_261516).

To clarify, the question [Edit answer draft is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266149/edit-answer-draft-is-broken) was published in September and for the Stack Exchange version 1.0.73. Is a different context.

Don't confuse the people or edit to remove relevant information. Someone could be going through the same!

Comment: +1. Are you sure you have v 1.0.71? [This issue was supposed to have been fixed as of 1.0.71](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261516/266359)....

Comment: I will try to erase every app data to make a clean installation.

Comment: Still happens after a clean installation :|

Comment: Repro'd on Android 5.1.1, app v1.0.72 beta. Seems a regression from previous version :(