# Edit answer draft is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, android-app, draft

The Edit Answer Draft button is broken.

- Press Back with text in an answer box.
- The Edit answer draft bar does not appear.

Seems like an `onBackPressed()` issue.

Also:

- Press ← with text in the answer box
- The bar appears.
- Click the bar
- The answer box is blank.

Seems like the answer isn't properly carried between the Fragments.

Either way, you lost everything you wrote.

Can somebody test this? And especially without a confirm dialog, it is a brush of the finger to lose a long post of code or something.

I hope this report will help because I like the app (I'd say 4/5 stars) but the bugs are preventing a solid 5 stars.

Stack Exchange 1.0.73
Samsung Galaxy S II Skyrocket I727
Android 4.1.2

Comment: Repro'd on SE app v1.0.73. Also (maybe) worth mentioning: After pressing in-app "back" button, the "Add an answer" button appears again on the bottom, along with the correct "Edit your answer draft" button.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this until now. A couple questions: Are we talking about drafts of _new_ answers or drafts for _editing_ an answer? When you say "Press Back with text in an answer box" are you talking about the button on the top left of the screen or the physical back button?

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the "Edit your answer draft" press --> Draft not showing up in the editor screen, I'm fixing that right now. I haven't been able to reproduce the case with the edit draft bar not showing when pressing back.

Answer (score 2):

I just finished doing a complete overhaul of now drafts are saved/stored. We now have much better support for drafts of answer edits, and the missing "Edit your answer draft" bar should no longer be missing in any situation.

This is implemented as of version 1.0.77, which is currently only in the beta channel. Do you mind joining the beta channel and giving me any feedback you have on this? You can find instructions to do so here: [Open beta testing of the Stack Exchange Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262151/open-beta-testing-of-the-stack-exchange-android-app)