# Android App sometimes loses answer drafts

Tags: bug, answers, android-app, draft

Often when I am writing an answer in the Android app I need to refer back to the question to confirm a point I have read, so I click the "back to question" button at top right.

When I go back to the question a button "edit your answer draft" appears at the bottom of screen as expected.

Clicking this button often takes me to an empty answer form with my draft work lost. A further "back" click takes me back to the question with no "edit answer draft" button.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the Android app?

Equipment: Samsung Galaxy S5 phone, Android 5.0

Comment: Repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0, SE app v1.0.75. Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266149/edit-answer-draft-is-broken

Answer (score 3):

This should be fixed as of version 1.0.77. It's currently only in the beta channel, do you mind joining the beta channel and testing it out? The instructions to join the beta channel are found here: [Open beta testing of the Stack Exchange Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262151/open-beta-testing-of-the-stack-exchange-android-app)

Comment: I downloaded the Beta, but the bug does not seem to be resolved.

Comment: @IanF1 in the About section of the app what version does it say you have? I may have jumped the gun a little too early, the beta tier is ran off Google Play which takes up to 2 hours to fully circulate a new version of the app.

Comment: Exact steps: 1. pressed "add answer" button. 2. Typed a test answer to the question. 3. Pressed the "left arrow" button in top left of the app. 4. Pressed "edit your answer draft" button. Answer box was empty. Also tried using the Preview feature in an attempt to force the draft to save.

Comment: That will be it! I'm apparently on Beta 1.0.76. Sorry for not checking! I'll try again in 2 hours

Comment: Awesome, sorry I forgot to mention that delay :)

Comment: Not working on 1.0.78 beta : http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270926/222299