# Android app drops my drafts

Tags: bug, answers, android-app, draft

The android app has started dropping my drafts to an answer. Usually when I write an answer I have to check back with the question that my answer is applicable.

In doing so the App just drops my draft and when I come back to amend my answer with necessary information I need to rewrite from scratch and (unsurprisingly) I don't remember my full answer nor do I remember everything I wanted to say in the first place.

Can we please have draft functionality again?

This is especially unnerving for technical sites where you want to add quotes from the original post or just check back.

I can not answer blindly :/

Comment: Might be fixed in beta channel, didn't try myself yet.

Comment: This is as of 1.0.78 beta, so still not fixed.

Comment: So worth letting Kasra know his fix isn't working.

Comment: Can you post the steps you are taking and list what's happening? Is the draft bar not showing up? When you tap to continue your draft is it failing to load then? What's actually happening for you?

Comment: @Kasra I start to write an answer, write some lines, then use the in-app 'back' button to get to the question. When I click on 'Add an answer' the editor is empty

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow when you hit the back button, you're not seeing a "Edit your answer draft" bar show up on the bottom of the screen? That's the real bug here.

Comment: what device and version of android are you running?

Comment: 5.0.1 on a Galaxy S 4. The bar you mention does not show up :/

Comment: Could it be that the draft bar just takes a moment to show up? After closing the app and reopening it, the bar shows up!