# Comment posting issue

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

There's a bug in the Android app where a comment can be typed in but not posted, meaning the post button does nothing and I have to back out of the question and go back in to post the comment. This definitely happens when the screen rotates, and also other times but I haven't identified them exactly.

I have version 1.0.78.

Edit: This had stopped happening but now started happening again when I updated to Android 6.0.1, now with version 1.0.85.

Comment: @Shadow it's not a duplicate because the answer says it should have been fixed in 1.0.77.

Comment: But see [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270926/android-app-drops-my-drafts#comment878289_270926) - isn't it the same for you? (just having to wait a bit) Anyway, as long as the dupe target is not marked [tag:status-completed], all same bug reports should be closed as dupe of it, and in case of such answer from a dev, we should let him know it's not working like Vogel did

Comment: That one's a different question, which is about the same thing indeed. It doesn't have the comment issue though.

Comment: Indeed, I experience this all the time. I think just scrolling the screen before clicking post make it then impossible to complete the operation. Then I have to copy the whole texte I typed, cancel and redo. Annoying...

Comment: The bug is still there in 1.0.85.

Comment: This is still definitely an issue.

Comment: I'm using the Android app so I can't see who edited. Whoever it was, the title change was too specific, as mentioned in the post. It definitely happens other times without rotating the screen.