# recover stackoverflow answer draft lost in android app

Tags: bug, android-app, draft

Was answering a question, went back to check a detail of the original question.

There was a option return to draft answer, tapped it, had some kind of error, now there is no draft option on the question to return to what I had typed out.

Anyway to recover this?

Comment: Is this related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219840/drafts-for-edits-get-lost-on-leaving-the-android-app?rq=1

Comment: Yes, except it seemed like it was indicating that there was a draft saved somewhere.  Like the button was labeled. It looked more like broken functionality than nonexistent functionality.

Comment: This is actually a bug, fixed in the beta channel but still not released.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for letting me know! Sorry for duplicate!

Comment: No problem, and hope it's really fixed in the beta. (didn't check it myself)