# Confirm post preview for low-rep posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, new-users

Those of us who have been using SO (or any SE site for that matter) for a while know that the box where we type our text is not identical to what is posted (because of various markdown capabilities we are given). We also know that there is a display below the text box that shows us what our post will actually look like once we are done, and we know how to format thing the way we would like them to look.

I've noticed a trend where a user will format things nicely (or somewhat nicely) as plaintext where they type, and ignore the fact that it is not at all formatted like that in the actual post (despite the fact that it is displayed, live, directly below where they are typing). Lists that are meant to span several lines appear as a single string across one line running onto several, code is partially code-formatted, etc...

I suggest that new users and users with many third-party edits (corrections by more experienced users), be prseented with a confirmation dialog when posting confirming that they have, in fact, checked out how their post will *actually* appear once posted, and that it is accurate. To address concerns regarding reduced conversions, a possible solution would be to bypass the dialog for absolute first posts, since those will be in First Post review queue anyway.

This will:

- Make it easier for everyone to read
- Reduce the amount of editing we have to do to make things readable
- Make it easier to take new, serious posters seriously, as their questions won't look lazy and effortless due to lack of formatting.

Mock up of dialog to be displayed:
[image]

Possible criteria for whether to display dialog:

```
if posts == 0:
    False
if posts < 5:  # questions AND answers
    True
if third_party_edits / posts > .3: # 30% "fixed" by others
    True
```

Comment: I was tempted to leave only one newline between each section, and not properly put the list together, but those things annoy me and I'm sure nobody would want to read such garbage.

Comment: Really? *I've* noticed a trend where low-rep/new/one-time users don't bother formatting their posts in the slightest, even when there's a preview right in front of them

Comment: @Fezziwig that's why I'd like to gently remind them as they post that they can do better, and that thay probably won't get a good answer unless they do...

Comment: This has a likely/certain effect of reducing conversions (posts). I honestly highly doubt quality will be improved much. Users that preview will be annoyed and users that don't will just find they have to click yet another box to proceed.

Comment: @Jim, I'd like to put a bounty on this question. do you mind if i edit it to include a mocked-up screenshot and a potential solution that addresses both issues raised in 2011?

Comment: @mhlester Please go right ahead!

Comment: I'd imagine it was considered an acceptable reason not to implement at the time

Answer (score 2):

First of all I think this is a good idea. Asking a question should be something that is given thought, and taking the time to ensure that the question is formatted properly is a part of that. "Training" new users to learn about markdown, and SO's formatting seems like a sensible thing to do.

I'm not sure about the conditions however. Maybe I'm a really bad speller (I am) and I get a bunch of edits, but I always format my posts beautifully. If there is a way to query the reason for edits maybe it could work.

Comment: Valid point. Might be too big of a query but just checking edits from within the first 10 minutes might help - those are more likely made by people trying to be able to read the code

Comment: Worst case scenario, it probably just 
gives up on you after a couple hundred rep :

Comment: Yea, once someone gets to I'd say... 200 maybe give up. That also brings up the issue of cross network rep.

Comment: keep in mind this proposal ultimately adds just one extra click to a targeted set of users. a few false positives shouldn't hurt much at all

Comment: Just a thought... Maybe instead of a full blown popup after they click create, maybe just a highlight on the realtime editor, with a message saying something like "This is what your post will look like.". This seems a little less invasive and reinforces the usage of the realtime editor.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to adjust user behavior with all the carrot and stick incentives, we should look to how we can adjust the Stack Overflow behavior so that the final view that will be seen is more apparent to the user.  (For example, look at the [MailChimp.com](http://mailchimp.com/) final form HTML editing or that of many other products.)

We should spend our time lobbying for improving the tools folks use here on SO rather than educating users in an older paradigm (what you see is not what you get).

Answer (score 0):

Came looking to make a very similar suggestion and found this old post.

To start, let's presume it's already determined the current user may need extra help to ask a good question. The specifics of criteria can be examined separately.

I think there should be new post state: "draft". A "draft post" would be distinct from [the "textarea draft" feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting). It should be much more similar to a normal submitted question -- it's actually submitted and displayed just like a normal question is.

The most important ways a "draft post" would be different are:

- include helpful suggestions & links to this user, e.g. [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  (also congratulatory messages for new users)
- signal to readers that the post may not be "ready", similar to new users having the "New Contributor" badge.
- actually look and feel like a normal post, in contrast to the textarea preview and popup modal suggestion
- this eagerly accepts imperfect submissions and trains users to go back to edit & improve an already-submitted question

Some concerns and possible ways to address/mitigate:

- lot of noisy "draft posts" -- perhaps they should be hidden from most users like deleted posts are and only the submitter and (optionally) higher-rep users can see them
- too many abandoned "draft posts" -- can choose to revert to today's behavior and auto-submit after X time, auto-expire drafts after Y time, or enforce a "max N drafts limit" like "textarea draft" feature does
- feature overlap with "Review your question" -- yes, but the semantics of a "draft post" are different (see "go back and edit", above). An alternative way to think of this entire suggestion is to "change Review your question feature look and act a lot more like a normal post, just with extra visual annotations".

Comment: It sounds like you've reinvented the [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416428/6083675).

Comment: oh wow, it's an entirely whole new workflow and interaction space

Answer (score -2):

Though I consider this as a good suggestion, I want you to note that it depends on users. I've seen users with more than 500 rep posting poorly formatted posts. Only the HTML formatting may be unaware for the new users. In all these cases there are a lot of experienced people here who are willing to format the post for them :) and I'm sure most of them will learn on the way.

Comment: @AnnaLear It looked good when it was like a quote :D

Comment: Perhaps, but that's not what quotes are for. They are for, well, quoting things. Please don't abuse the markup; otherwise your posts are harder to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, the irony... :)