# Confirmation Before First Post

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown, new-users, code-formatting

Related: [Confirm post preview for low-rep posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116936/confirm-post-preview-for-low-rep-posts)

Should first posters be required to click through a screen showing their *formatted* post, confirming they approve of how it looks before submitting? **So often** code isn't indented properly; this would give the OP an opportunity to fix it so others don't have to.

Certainly if they're stuck, someone else can fix it for them as is often the case now, but oftentimes it's a simple matter of not realizing it'll look the way it does. (hence the flurry of edits after the post is made)

This is compounded by the fact that improperly formatted code becomes very small, and easy to miss on the scroll down to <kbd>Post Your Question</kbd>

Perhaps beyond just a minimum rep, it would also be based on how often other users have edited their posts, as a metric for how well they've historically done it right.

---

Edit: this question has been closed as a dupe. While I see the *very* close relation between the two, the lone answer on the other post explicitly does not address my recommendation of which users to present the confirmation to. I.E. Base it on the number of third-party edits the poster has received.

So tell me this: if my question is closed as a dupe, and the other question doesn't answer this question, how does one go about getting a relevant answer? Do I need to open a bounty on the other post? That seems overkill for a question that hardly benefits me as an individual.

Comment: Hmm... It's almost a dupe of that. But the only answer doesn't address my suggestion of basing it on other edits. If this is closed as dupe, what's the correct protocol for getting proper answer? Do I need to open a bounty on the other post?

Comment: I agree that the other post doesn't really address your suggestion though. I guess the mod can let this suggestion open first and wait until it's resolved.

Comment: It also amazes me how people manage to get around the place without reading any wall of text. Users have been conditioned to just scroll to the bottom and click "OK", instead of actually reading what's there.

Comment: but it is already shown below the post in another <div> that how the post will look like.

Comment: @VishwasSharma, I address that in the third paragraph. They miss that they're reading the rendered post
 when the fact that they didn't indent makes it a fraction of the size they'd expect. If it were effective for new users, we wouldn't see nearly as many malformed posts

Comment: Until they learn where to look, they should be presented with an action item to confirm it. The *problem* is undeniable, but I'd be open to other *solutions*

Comment: `Post Your Question` button is only shown after the user is displayed how his/her post will look like. There is another thing, On StackOverFlow, I have seen many new users posting all of their code, 90% of which is unnecessary and it also covers several pages (2-3 normally) which consist of text, then code, then text and repeat it several times. Now, imagine this confirmation box, which is scrollable consist of such a big post and also providing view for code, text, code and so on, on top of background main screen. Won't it become a bit messy in itself

Comment: `While I see the very close relation between the two... if my question is closed as a dupe, and the other question doesn't answer this question, how does one go about getting a relevant answer?` You throw your weight behind promoting the original, for example by adding a brief edit or comment to include your additional quirk. In this case, in the context of meta, consider adding your idea as a potential _answer_ for that question.

Comment: I appreciate your response @JoelCorhoorn. The answer idea is strange to me coming 
from SO where answers are so well delineated. I did end up getting permission from the other asker to heavily edit and post a bounty. So full steam ahead on that one. Meta sure is a different beast than what I'm used to

Comment: One last thing @JoelCoehoorn: perhaps the close reason text should be edited to remove the misleading line "If those answers do not fully address your question" as that apparently has no bearing on whether it should be closed or not

Comment: It makes more sense when you realize your Question here really has two parts: the problem, and the proposed solution. The other question is really asking about the same problem, but offers a different solution. In those situations, we want one single Question for the problem, with each proposed solution as a new answer.

Comment: Ah, that clicked. Thanks!