# Allow Shorter Duration Bounties

Tags: feature-request, bounties, bountied-tab

I don't personally have an immediate need for this, but it seems like there must be those for whom it could be a life saver.

Allow bounties to be placed with shorter duration. Since the Featured page is sorted by date, this allows the question to jump higher on the list and gain more immediate exposure.

This *does not* increase the total exposure the question receives. Rather, it moves up the timetable of the question, giving it the exposure it already would get, but sooner. In fact, it reduces the total exposure.

This could be exceedingly useful for questions where OP has a deadline, and needs more immediate answers.

I can't think of any drawbacks to this, beyond the additional step of selecting from a dropdown (1-7 days, but default 7), and of course developer time to implement.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian, good point. But what if you already want to offer +500?

Comment: It's maxed at 500

Comment: To prioritize this for people who have time-sensitive needs, I would like to include a tax (say, an extra 50% on top of your bounty) to use a shorter-duration bounties.  Similarly, eBay charges a little extra for very short or very long auctions.

Comment: I like it (+1) but the problem I see here is that _everyone_ would use this feature because most people who put bounties have "urgent issues" anyway. This means that eventually questions would simply get less exposure.

Comment: In my admittedly limited experience, I haven't noticed most bounties to be urgent. I have been awarded two (on SO) and have offered one (Meta). [Only one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219248/how-to-install-oct2py-on-windows) of those three could have *possibly* been urgent.  The other two definitely were not ([18 months](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715724/weird-ipython-ipdb-behaviour), and [2 years](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116936/confirm-post-preview-for-low-rep-posts) after question posted)

Comment: As an alternative the default ordering of the bounty tab could be random; allowing consistent exposure over the lifetime of the bounty