# How long do saved drafts exist?

Tags: support, answers, draft

When I type an answer to any question and suddenly decide I have better things to do, the answer gets saved as a draft.

If I return to that question say a week later, will my draft still exist? I figure there must be some sort of lifespan for every draft.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I return to that question say a week later, will my draft still exist?

Drafts will be automatically cleared after **a week**. Also note if one of your answer is saved in draft and you start a new answer then the old one will be cleared.

[Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/187824)

Comment: As in, do the cleaning scripts run once a week, or will drafts be deleted after seven days?

Comment: Where did you get this fact from? Did you actually test it out?

Comment: @Telthien - the draft will be cleared **after a week**.

Comment: @AnishRam - See the updated answer.

Comment: @hims056 After a week of the draft or the server's existence?

Comment: @hims056, Thanks for that (I had already checked that out, but somehow seemed to have missed that point). That answer was posted in April, 2011. Does it still apply?

Comment: @Telthien - Obviously after a week of the draft.

Comment: @AnishRam - Remember to know any changes in any feature of Stack Exchange see [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/187824)

Comment: Why is my page *[apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)* empty ? I had started to write a question, it was at most 3 days ago.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco - If you are sure for that, you may post a bug report here.

Comment: @hims056 — I have posted this bug report here : [*Draft is lost way before the one week limit*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233732/draft-is-lost-way-before-the-one-week-limit).