# Draft is lost way before the one week limit

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, draft

I have found my page [*apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) empty.

I had started to write a question, my draft was at most 3 days old. My draft was way younger than 1 week. [So it was supposed to be saved and restored.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175784/how-long-do-saved-drafts-exist)

I have encountered this bug twice.

It would be nice to fix this bug.

Comment: @user0000000 — This was my last draft question I had on the site. If I had another draft question on the site, I should have seen the other one, not an empty page. I did not delete the draft question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard — Ah, this may be an explanation. During such operations, it would be nice to save and restore this data.

Comment: @ShadowWizard — So you mean that there is a bug in the system itself, even when no server is being moved.

Comment: @ShadowWizard — I don’t know who the Oded is…

Comment: I just checked the code and drafts are saved for 72 hours at a time (despite being advertised as 1 week). This could be due to a change since the Wiki entry. I'll see what the team thinks about saving them for one week.

Comment: @Haney — This must be a regression. I understand that you have fixed it now.

Comment: Stop messing up your question. Please. If you don't understand why links were replaced, ***ASK***. They were changed for a good reason.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Why did you change the links? The help says: respect the original author's writing. Please do so; thank you. The page was `http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask`.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco **All SE links are now changed from `http` to `https`, and all meta URLs are now changed from `meta.sitename.stackexchange.com` into `sitename.meta.stackexchange.com`.**

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco no, I will not stop making the posts here better. You may disagree, it's your full right, but it's not your right to make the post quality worse on purpose.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for bringing this up. After chatting with the team (Marc Gravell) and confirming that increasing the draft duration would not be an issue performance-wise, I have bumped it from 3 days to 7 days. This will be live in the next production release.

Comment: Great news ! Thank you Haney.